# Why does my For loop not work in django template

Tags: python, django-templates

I'm trying to get all invoices of one transaction. Because there are some possibilities to pay partly, that's why I need to get a history of transactions. I've included another HTML to my current HTML with 'include' and with. But at the end for loop it doesn't show anything, at the same time there are no errors.

Here is my views.py:

```py
def transaction_history(request, transaction_id):
    transaction = get_object_or_404(Transaction, pk=transaction_id)
    invoices = Invoice.objects.filter(transaction=transaction).order_by('-created_at')
    return render(request, 'front/transaction_history.html', {'invoices': invoices, 'transaction': transaction })
```

Here is my template:

```py
{% for invoice in invoices%}
    <tr>
       <td>{{ invoice.created_at }}</td>
       <td>{{ invoice.created_by }} </td>
       <td>{{ invoice.amount|floatformat:-2 }}</td>
       {% for item in transaction %}
          <td>{{ item.is_payed }}</td>
       {% endfor %}}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Here is my include link:

```py
{% include 'front/transaction_history.html' with invoices=invoices only %}
```

Comment: can you please mention, what error/result you got?

Comment: there is no error, just for loop doesn't show anything. There is empty

Comment: Your invoices variable may be empty. Can you check this in the view?